# How to Change Radio Button Color in Spinner

Tags: android, radio-button, spinner

When I use spinner with radio button, selecting color in radio button seems default. I want to change the default color of radio button set in spinner in Android. How can I do it?

[image: The color I want to change (click to see)]

string file for spinner:

```
    <string-array name="Departments">
    <item>Body Exterior</item>
    <item>Body Interior</item>
    <item>Chassis</item>
    <item>EESE</item>
    <item>Powertrain</item>
    <item>Vehicle Engineering</item>
    <item>Other</item>
```

xml file for spinner:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spnDepartments"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:gravity="left" />
</LinearLayout>
```

java file for spinner:

```
Spinner spnDepartments;
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

   spnDepartments = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnDepartments);
   adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.Departments,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice);
    spnDepartments.setAdapter(adapter1);
    spnDepartments.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
      }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control the color of the radio buttons within your spinner by setting the *theme attributes* `colorAccent` (for the selected radio button) and `colorControlNormal` (for the unselected buttons).

Normally, these are set in your app's (or your activity's) theme (the style referenced from `android:theme` in your manifest). But if you want to override them for a single `Spinner`, you can do that too.

First, create a `<style>` that has the colors you want:

```
<style name="SpinnerTheme">
    <item name="colorAccent">#00f</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#00f</item>
</style>
```

Then, apply this style as your Spinner's theme:

```
<Spinner
    android:theme="@style/SpinnerTheme"
    .../>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Android:buttonTint="@color/yourcolor"
```

but it only works with API 21 or above

Comment: It is API 25 but does not accept the sentence. What I want is to set color radio button in spinner. I guess your answer is just for radio button?